# google safebrowsing api response : Deadline expired before operation could complete

Tags: quota, safe-browsing

I'm using the google safebrowsing api for getting fullhashes for the prefixes of hashes of url present in threat lists. When i'm using 5 threads to do the job, the job completes but the latency is high, so i tried increasing the threads to 7 and more but i'm getting the following error on doing that:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 504 Gateway Time-out
{
  "code" : 504,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Deadline expired before operation could complete.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Deadline expired before operation could complete.",
  "status" : "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED"
}
```

But, I'm sure that my daily quota has not exceeded.
By looking at the console, i can see that the number of requests per second is not more than the default quota (3000 req/100sec).
What other reason can be there for the above error ?